# Python Text file resets to 1 after hitting 10

Tags: python

My code contains a portion that opens a text file, reads the first number, adds one to it, and replaces the number.

However, once it hits 10, the script only reads the "1" because it's the first number, and I can't figure out how to tell it to read the whole first line.

Here's my code:

```
f = open("numlog.txt","r")
line = f.readline()
x = int(line[0])
f.close()                                                           
x +=1
x = str(x)
f = open("numlog.txt","w")
f.write(x) 
f.close()
```

Comment: My bad, ignore the "counter". I tried to edit it out but am unable to.

Comment: The problem isn't *reading* the first line, which `readline` does just fine, but **think about what `x = int(line[0])` is doing with it!** Also, you should open files using the *"context manager"*: `with open(...) as f:`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do - `x = int(line[0])` , you are only reading the first character from the first line.

So lets say your line is - `10` , so you would only read `1` as that is the first character , `0` is the second character in the line.

You should read the complete line instead as -

```
x = int(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the first number, which presumably could be any number of characters, `line[0]` only reads the first character.  If there is no other text on the line, then convert the whole line, but there could be other non-numeric text, so you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

line = '10 hello there'

m = re.match(r'(\d+)', line)
if m:
    x = int(m.groups()[0])
else:
    print "No number found"
```